# How can I store and track points in classes?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I am recently learning about python class and as my first code I learnt about making a "point" class whom object has two parameter x and y and it can also calculate distance between two diff point or object belonging to same point class....I decided to play with it and tried defining a point class which can track the coordinates to which single point object moved and can store that data into the list....so that I can define a function called show-point in this class which can show me all the points to which my single point moved and also calculate individual distance between one movement and final displacement.....I tried defining an empty list before function definition but this list is storing coordinates for all diff point and when moved with in function it does not work...WHERE AM I WRONG?

```
class point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        l1 = []
        self.move(x,y)
    def move(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        l1 = [(self.x,self.y)]
        l1.append((x,y))
    def showpoint(self):
        for i in l1:
            print(i)

B = point(0,0)
B.move(1,1)
B.move(2,2)
B.move(3,3)
B.showpoint()
```

Error:
name 'l1' is not defined

Comment: Should be `self.l1`?

Comment: self.l1 is working but it is only returning the last moved point by an object not the whole path

Comment: Point doesn't have any method or data associated with a path.  So showpoint only returns the last position of the point.

Comment: So how can I do that?